# C# command not writing a line

Tags: c#

Well hello, how do I make this console write a line? I managed to make it so it run the cmd.exe when u process it, but it doesnt write the line.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "alpha")
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 100;
            if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome back master!");
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe");
                Console.WriteLine("Hello!!!");
            }

        }
```

Comment: You got no entry point.

Comment: where are you writing the line?

Comment: I think he wants to start a command line from a winform app and then write the line to the new console.

Comment: How do i make it work? I am new to c#. Also this is not the entire code, this is only the part of the code that's giving me troubles.@AlinaB Yes!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472282/show-console-in-windows-application

Comment: If you want to create a console for your winform application, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917202/how-do-i-include-a-console-in-winforms) could be helpful.

Comment: And somewhat relevant discussion: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/fd89cf64-eab4-4cc5-8f35-74ec848d8a60

Comment: And this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807998/how-do-i-create-a-c-sharp-app-that-decides-itself-whether-to-show-as-a-console-o also seems relevant

Comment: I am curious.. why would you want your WinForms app to write to a command console? Why not just append it to some multiline textbox for example?

Answer (score 8):

if you want to interact with the console process, you need to do it like this :-

```
var p = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe", 
                UseShellExecute = false, 
                RedirectStandardInput = true, 
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            }
    };
p.Start();
var w = p.StandardInput;                
w.WriteLine("Dir");
w.WriteLine("Exit");            
var theDirectoryListing = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
w.Close();            
p.Close();
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume this is a method that you somehow manage to call. The System.Diagnostics.Process.Start call will create a command box. However Console.WriteLine will try to write to whichever created your process (which is not the cmd.exe on the line above) and if it is a desktop app the call will have no console to write to, thus no message for you.