# Console in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, console

According to [THIS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/701e02cc-ad77-46b9-b4fc-410bb3ff7a0d/using-a-console-with-a-windows-form?forum=csharpgeneral)

The following code should show a console window and write "test"in it. However the console windows does come up but Console.Writeline("test"); will do nothing.

```
namespace consoleTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            AllocConsole();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool AllocConsole();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
        }
    }
}
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: Looks like you need to add a standard out to the console window you've just created. See accepted answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7a14400-6d72-4fbf-9927-0966f69ef4a2/how-to-open-console-window-in-windows-apllication?forum=csharplanguage).

Comment: I have tested the code you posted and works fine (`Console.WriteLine` do its work).

Comment: for me it clearly does not work

Comment: Try to move the `Console.WriteLine("test");` inside ctor. Are you sure the `Form1_Load` is called?

Comment: Yes i am sure. Whenever i debug my application, Console.Writeline will be called but it just won't write.

Comment: I had this implemented in a bigger application. It just suddenly stopped working in every application of mine. I suspect something in my Windows is has gone wrong. A reboot will probaly fix it. Can it has to do something with disposing?

Comment: I've found this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917202/how-do-i-include-a-console-in-winforms

might be useful?

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting my pc solved this problem. Why did it solve my problem? No idea.

If anyone knows why this problem did occur feel free to post it as an answer!

Comment: You would have had an opportunity to find out why if you had added the required error checking code.  AllocConsole() returns *bool*, you are supposed to throw a Win32Exception if it returns false so you *know* why it failed.  Too late now.

Comment: Can you provide the exact code you described? You never know when it might go wrong again.

Comment: if (!AllocConsole()) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();